# Swift 3 - How to upload image with parameters to mysql

Tags: swift, swift3

This code I use in Upload (I found it in a tutorial) is working successfully but the parameters is not being recognised instead of WHERE emp_name ='(insert employee)'it says emp_name='' because i'm trying to update the URL with the newly uploaded picture. Please help. i'm new to this.

```
 func UploadRequest()
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/empupload.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (imageDetail.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageDetail.image!)


    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }


    let body = NSMutableData()
    let loadempname = NSMutableURLRequest()


    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"
    let postString = "empName=\(empname.text!))"


    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


    body.append(postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


    request.httpBody = body as Data



    let session = URLSession.shared


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard ((data) != nil), let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            print(dataString)
        }

    })


    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a third-party library like Alamofire for these complex requests.

Comment: `\(empname.text!))` why there is two closing brackects while there is only one open bracket? Try removing one closing bracket

Comment: I'll try removing the bracket

Comment: Tried removing the bracket and the output is still the same.

Comment: Update! I used Alamofire and the parameters I used is now working and the photo URL in finally updating in mysql 

Answer (score 1):

You can post image through Alamofire multipartFormData in swift3.0. Here is sample code:

```
let  parameters = ["name":"YourName"]

Alamofire.upload(.POST, baseUrl, multipartFormData:
{
    multipartFormData in

    if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.6)
    {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "keyName", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
     }
     for (key, value) in parameters
     {
          if value is String || value is Int
          {
              multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
           }

      }
}, encodingCompletion:
    {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult
        {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                if String(response.result) == "SUCCESS"
                {
                    if(response.result.value!.objectForKey("status")) as! String != "fail"
                    {
                        // here you can write success case
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MyLoadingView.dismiss();
                    MyAlertView.showErrorAlert("Please try Again" )
                }
            }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
```

Comment: How do I insert the url in the baseUrl? alamofire installed.

Comment: let baseUrl = "Your url"